# How do I flow in a circle on a set of vector fields?

Tags: differential-geometry, control-theory, vector-fields

Consider a set of complete vector fields on a manifold. They each have an associated one parameter group of diffeomorphisms related to the generated flow.

What is a necessary and sufficient condition on the vector fields such that a point is able to flow forwards in a loop by hopping between flows?

Any theorems, further reading, or related posts regarding conditions on sets of flows would be helpful.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but here's a random possibly related conjecture which I have no idea whether it's true (or even whether it's known whether it's true). Let $X_1, \dots, X_k$ be an involutive set of complete vector fields on a manifold $M$ and let $N$ be an integral manifold of these fields. Suppose that for every $p$ in $N$, the *nonnegative* span of $X_1(p), \dots, X_k(p)$ is equal to $T_pN$. Is it then true that one can get from any $p \in N$ to any $q \in N$ by following the flows of the $X_i$?

Comment: @XipanXiao, by forwards I mean only using positive parameters. So some loops will necessarily contain segments that require negative parameters. I want to ignore these.